# In angular-google-maps, what's the right way to bind to click events on a polygon

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to bind a function to a click event on a polygon in Google maps using angular-google-maps. Here's how I define the polygon:

```
 <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
    <ui-gmap-polygon static="true" ng-repeat="p in polygons track by p.id" 
                     path="p.path" stroke="p.stroke" visible="p.visible"
                     fill="p.fill" clickable="true" events="p.events">
     </ui-gmap-polygon>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

and here's the code in the controller:

```
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 3, longitude: 49 }, zoom: 7 };

    // preset polygons
    $scope.polygons = [
        {
            id: 1,
            path: [
                { latitude: 12, longitude: 50 },
                { latitude: 27, longitude: 54 },
                { latitude: 24, longitude: 45 },
            ],
            stroke: { color: '#ff0000', weight: 2 },
            visible: true,
            fill: { color: '#ff0000', opacity: 0.3 },
            events: { click: function() { console.log("clicked!"); }},
        }
    ];
```

The polygon appears fine and everything, the only problem is that I can't bind the click event. Can anyone help me figure out the right way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey found an [**answer**](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/560) for you. So this is possible and please read till the end of the thread as they explain how to attach click listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out that my problem was actually related to mobile (more specifically, Ionic). There's a difference between tap and click.

Found this solution: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/428
Works great.